# How to open a specific subform in navigation form through vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to close and reopen my subform in 2 step navigation for.

```
  DoCmd.Close
  DoCmd.OpenForm "Dashboard", acNormal, , , , acWindowNormal
    DoCmd.BrowseTo acBrowseToForm, "NavCompReport", "Main.NavigationSubform>FindClientsNavigation.NavigationSubform"
```

Below is the form which I am trying to close and reopen.

[image]

Comment: That seems a very long winded process - why are you closing then reopening it ?